# How to generate weighted multi-stage table (frequency as well as percentage) using frequency weight in R?

Tags: r, survey

I have a survey data set with frequency weight (freq_wgt). The survey design is multi-stage cluster sampling. The data set if following.

```
sector <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2)
sex <- c(2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2)
group <- c(1,2,3,3, 2,1,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,3,3,1,3,1,2,2)
freq_wgt <- c(2,4,5,6,3,4,5,3,2,5,6,7,5,4,3,5,7,8,9,1)
df <- data.frame(sector, sex, group, freq_wgt)

df$sector <- factor(df$sector, levels = c(1,2), labels = c("Rural", "Urban"))
df$sex <- factor(df$sex, levels = c(1,2), labels = c("Male", "Female"))
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels = c(1,2,3), labels = c("STs", "SCs", "Others"))
```

I want to generate following kind of multi-strata table (frequency as well as col/row percentage) after applying the frequency weight.

```
mytable <- ftable(xtabs(~ sector + sex + group, data= df))
print(mytable)
```

Note: I found wtd.table function from Hmisc package but not suitable as it only generate one stage strata table. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the design below assumes simple random sampling.  you'll need to look at the tech docs and/or `?svydesign` to see how to make it account for multi-stage cluster sampling.

```
library(survey)
my_design <- svydesign( ~ 1 , data = df , weights = ~ freq_wgt )
svytable( ~ sector + sex + group , my_design )
svyby( ~ sector , ~ sex + group , my_design , svymean )
svyby( ~ sex , ~ sector + group , my_design , svymean )
svyby( ~ group , ~ sector + sex , my_design , svymean )
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [this example (in section 2.1.4) on the NHANES dataset](https://bookdown.org/mpfoley1973/survey/analyzing-survey-data.html#exploring-categorical-items), you can simply use `svytable` and then calculate a percentage from the totals.

```
require(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
    sector = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2)), 
    sex = c(2,1,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2,2), 
    group = c(1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,3,3,1,3,1,2,2), 
    freq_wgt = c(2,4,5,6,3,4,5,3,2,5,6,7,5,4,3,5,7,8,9,1))

df$sector <- factor(c("Rural", "Urban")[df$sector])
df$sex <- factor(c("Male", "Female")[df$sex])
df$group <- factor(c("STs", "SCs", "Others")[df$group])

# define survey design object
# my_design <- ...

svytable(~sex, design = my_design) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(prop = Freq / sum(Freq) * 100)
```

Similarly, in a more hacky way, you could add a dummy variable to the dataset and take `svymean` of that, which will give you percentages for categorical variables

```
# (define data as above)

# Create dummy variable
df$dummy <- 1

# define design object
# my_design <- ...

svyby(~sex, ~dummy, svymean, design = my_design)
```